# Calling mainActivity method through Fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-viewpager2

I have implemented fragment in viewpager and Fragment has some buttons. Also viewpager is in activity_main layout.

I want that when button is clicked then it implement a method which is mentioned in mainActivity.java.

How can I do this?

I am a beginner.

Comment: Please add what you've tried and add your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get MainActivity method from fragment like below. 
Make sure your methid is public if MainActivity and ViewPager are not in same package.

```
((MainActivity) getActivity()).getMethodOfMain();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call getActivity Method from your fragment and cast it to the your respective Activity.

lets take an example : You Have MainActivity class

```
MainActivity { 

public void check() {}

}
```

And you have fragment : MainFragment

```
MainFragment{ 

Activity mainActivity  = (MainActivity) getActivity();
mainActivity.check();

}
```

Thats how you can call the Respective Activity Method.